# xorg-xdm cannot output Cyrillic text

Tags: x11, xorg, fonts, xdm

The [Ubuntu Nerd font](https://www.nerdfonts.com/) is installed on the system.

`xfontsel` defines the font. As you can see in the screenshot, the Cyrillic alphabet is displayed correctly (the last line)

[image]

`man iso_8859-5` it tells me under which code I can get one or another character of my encoding

[image]

In the `Xresources` configuration file I am specifying the sequence of the Cyrillic alphabet:

```
...
Xlogin*titleMessage:             \260\261\262\263\264\265\266
xlogin*greeting:                 \260\261\262\263\264\265\266
xlogin*namePrompt:               Username:\040
xlogin*passwdPrompt:             Password:\040
xlogin*fail:                     Authentication failed
...
xlogin*greetFont:                -*-ubuntu nerd font-*-r-normal-*-17-120-100-100-*-*-iso8859-5
xlogin*font:                     -*-ubuntu nerd font-*-r-normal-*-17-120-100-100-*-*-iso8859-5
xlogin*promptFont:               -*-ubuntu nerd font-*-r-normal-*-17-120-100-100-*-*-iso8859-5
xlogin*failFont:                 -*-ubuntu nerd font-*-r-normal-*-17-120-100-100-*-*-iso8859-5
xlogin*greetFace:                Ubuntu Nerd Font-14:bold
xlogin*face:                     Ubuntu Nerd Font-10
xlogin*promptFace:               Ubuntu Nerd Font-12:bold
xlogin*failFace:                 Ubuntu Nerd Font-10:bold
```

But when starting `xdm`, I get the wrong characters that I specified in the configuration file.

[image]

What could be the problem?

I have already tried various solutions to the problems. The `locale` is set in the required encoding. The `Xresources` file is also in UTF-8 format. I've already tried everything. But as a result, when I output the text, I get a two-byte representation of each Cyrillic character. It feels like `xdm` doesn't understand UTF-8.

UPD1:

Unicode is not output

```
Xlogin*titleMessage:             Добро пожаловать
xlogin*greeting:                 Добро пожаловать
xlogin*namePrompt:               Пользователь:\040
xlogin*passwdPrompt:             Пароль:\040
xlogin*fail:                     Ошибка аутентификации

xlogin*greetFont:                -*-ubuntumono nerd font mono-*-r-normal-*-17-120-100-100-m-*-iso8859-5
xlogin*font:                     -*-ubuntumono nerd font mono-*-r-normal-*-17-120-100-100-m-*-iso8859-5
xlogin*promptFont:               -*-ubuntumono nerd font mono-*-r-normal-*-17-120-100-100-m-*-iso8859-5
xlogin*failFont:                 -*-ubuntumono nerd font mono-*-r-normal-*-17-120-100-100-m-*-iso8859-5
xlogin*greetFace:                Ubuntumono Nerd Font-14:bold:italic
xlogin*face:                     Ubuntumono Nerd Font-10
xlogin*promptFace:               Ubuntumono Nerd Font-12:bold
xlogin*failFace:                 Ubuntumono Nerd Font-10:bold
```

[image]

UPD2:

Another setting option. It feels like `xdm` doesn't see the specified font:

[image]

```
xlogin*titleMessage:             Добро пожаловать
xlogin*greeting:                 Добро пожаловать
xlogin*namePrompt:               Пользователь:\040
xlogin*passwdPrompt:             Пароль:\040
xlogin*fail:                     Ошибка аутентификации

xlogin*greetFont:                -*-ubunt nerd font-*-r-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-uni
xlogin*font:                     -*-ubunt nerd font-*-r-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-uni
xlogin*promptFont:               -*-ubunt nerd font-*-r-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-uni
xlogin*failFont:                 -*-ubunt nerd font-*-r-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-uni
xlogin*greetFace:                Ubuntu Nerd Font-14:bold:italic
xlogin*face:                     Ubuntu Nerd Font-10
xlogin*promptFace:               Ubuntu Nerd Font-12:bold
xlogin*failFace:                 Ubuntu Nerd Font-10:bold
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The greeter for xdm (in Debian and derived systems) uses Xft for drawing the string (see [source code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xdm/-/blob/master/greeter/Login.c?ref_type=heads#L282)):

```c
# define DRAW_STRING(f, x, y, m, l) \
    /* Debug("DRAW_STRING(%s, %d, %d, %s, %d)\n", #f, x, y, m, l); */ \
    XftDrawString8 (w->login.draw, &w->login.f##color, w->login.f##Face, \
            x, y, (FcChar8 *) (m), l)
```

Xft provides a few variations of string-drawing (see [manual](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xft/xft.html#h3-Families-of-Functions)):

```
Families of Functions
       Xft provides groups of drawing functions which differ according to  the
       way  the  data is encoded, e.g., 8-bit (ISO-8859-1) versus UTF-8.  Here
       is a summary of these related functions:

       Encoding   XftDrawString*       XftTextExtents*       XftTextRender*
       -------------------------------------------------------------------------
       8          XftDrawString8       XftTextExtents8       XftTextRender8
       16         XftDrawString16      XftTextExtents16      XftTextRender16
       16BE       XftDrawString16      XftTextExtents16      XftTextRender16BE
       16LE       XftDrawString16      XftTextExtents16      XftTextRender16LE
       32         XftDrawString32      XftTextExtents32      XftTextRender32
       32BE       XftDrawString32      XftTextExtents32      XftTextRender32BE
       32LE       XftDrawString32      XftTextExtents32      XftTextRender32LE
       UTF-8      XftDrawStringUtf8    XftTextExtentsUtf8    XftTextRenderUtf8
       UTF-16     XftDrawStringUtf16   XftTextExtentsUtf16   XftTextRenderUtf16
```

The greeter uses **`greetFont`** for the non-Xft configuration (see [source code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xdm/-/blob/master/greeter/Login.c?ref_type=heads#L169)):

```c
#ifndef USE_XFT
    {XtNfont, XtCFont, XtRFontStruct, sizeof (XFontStruct *),
    offset (textFont), XtRString,   "*-new century schoolbook-medium-r-normal-*-180-*"},
    {XtNpromptFont, XtCFont, XtRFontStruct, sizeof (XFontStruct *),
    offset (promptFont), XtRString, "*-new century schoolbook-bold-r-normal-*-180-*"},
    {XtNgreetFont, XtCFont, XtRFontStruct, sizeof (XFontStruct *),
    offset (greetFont), XtRString,  "*-new century schoolbook-bold-i-normal-*-240-*"},
    {XtNfailFont, XtCFont, XtRFontStruct, sizeof (XFontStruct *),
    offset (failFont), XtRString,   "*-new century schoolbook-bold-r-normal-*-180-*"},
#else /* USE_XFT */
    {XtNface, XtCFace, XtRXftFont, sizeof (XftFont *),
        offset (textFace), XtRString, "Serif-18"},
    {XtNpromptFace, XtCFace, XtRXftFont, sizeof (XftFont *),
        offset (promptFace), XtRString, "Serif-18:bold"},
    {XtNgreetFace, XtCFace, XtRXftFont, sizeof (XftFont *),
        offset (greetFace), XtRString, "Serif-24:italic"},
    {XtNfailFace, XtCFace, XtRXftFont, sizeof (XftFont *),
        offset (failFace), XtRString, "Serif-18:bold"},
    {XtNforeground, XtCForeground, XtRXftColor, sizeof(XftColor),
        offset(textcolor), XtRString,   XtDefaultForeground},
    {XtNpromptColor, XtCForeground, XtRXftColor, sizeof(XftColor),
        offset(promptcolor), XtRString, XtDefaultForeground},
    {XtNgreetColor, XtCForeground, XtRXftColor, sizeof(XftColor),
        offset(greetcolor), XtRString,  XtDefaultForeground},
    {XtNfailColor, XtCForeground, XtRXftColor, sizeof (XftColor),
    offset(failcolor), XtRString,   XtDefaultForeground},
#endif
```

The xdm manpage tells you about this difference:

```
       xlogin.Login.greetFace
              The face used to display the greeting when built with  Xft  sup‐
              port.  The default is ‘‘Serif‐24:italic’’.

       xlogin.Login.greetFont
              The  font  used  to display the greeting when not built with Xft
              support.
```

Because you did not configure a font face, the greeter uses the default font (which according to the Xft manual, is limited to an eight-bit encoding such as ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-5).

Comment: So, I have specified these parameters in the configuration. Nothing changes. My question shows the configuration of the font setting, where I specified both `xlogin*greetFont` and `xlogin*greetFace`.